# how i can ONLY get all the users but not doing it in FOREACH way ??(PDO/PHP)

Tags: php, pdo

I like this to happen:

`if(email === emails) {` if one matches the email in the emails table, it will return true

i dont know how to code it.

the thing I know is to this

`$emails = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM emails");`

then when i try to fetch it via like this

```
$result = $emails->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

it says try to get a non-object ......

So please any code you can suggest I try. Thanks

HERE IS THE RESULT: to the var_dump

```
object(DB)#3 (6) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(37) "SELECT email FROM emails" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["email"]=> string(18) "abinuman@yahoo.com" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#8 (1) { ["email"]=> string(17) "ryeniel@yahoo.com" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) { ["email"]=> string(15) "email@yahoo.com" } } ["_fetchAll":"DB":private]=> NULL ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(3) }
```

Comment: Dump the users variable and check what it contains (`var_dump($users);`) before `$users->fetchAll()`.

Comment: can i post here what is the result ?

Comment: I edit it. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Btw. isn't better to query the database for that email instead of fetching all?

Comment: I have a query. uhm, i only try the fetchAll because, i do not know how to SELECT all the emails in the emails table, the only thing I can SELECT properly is to foreach the emails, and it will result all the emails available in  the table. BUT I do not want it, I only want to confirm if THE email is existing in the emails table.

Comment: Why you are not adding the `where` clause with the `email` field? LIke `DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT email FROM emails AND email = '" . $email . "'");` and one more thing please use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injections;

Comment: you must be looking for [PDO::fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 like this? WHERE email = $users->email

Comment: @diEcho trying to get a property of non-object

Comment: you printed the `$emails` var, while you have to print the `$result` var.

Comment: Yes man but i don't know where is the `email` you are trying to compare with the records in database;

Comment: @wajeeh No, when I try to vardump $emails, I do this "//" in the $result

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I was trying to do this: if($usersEmail === $emailsTable(example only)) then it will return or false depends if it is coorect or not